# Writing integers to a file errors

Tags: java, file, numberformatexception

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        writeToFile ("c:\\scores.txt");
        processFile("c:\\scores.txt");
    }
    public static void writeToFile (String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Num;
        System.out.println ("Please enter 7 scores");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

                Num= reader.nextInt ();

                outputWriter.write(Num);      

                if(i!=6) {
                    outputWriter.newLine();
                }
            }

        outputWriter.flush(); 
        outputWriter.close();
}

    public static void processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException 
    {
        double sum=0.00;
        double number;
        double average;
                int count = 0;
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        String line;

        while((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            number= Double.parseDouble(line); 
                        System.out.println(number);
                        count ++;
            sum += (number);
            System.out.print ("Total Sum:  ");
            System.out.println(sum);
            System.out.print("Average of Scores:  ");
            average=sum/count;
            System.out.println(average);
        }       
        inputReader.close();
    }
```

This is what my output is.

```
Please enter 7 scores
2
3
5
6
8
9
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at writefile.Writefile.processFile(Writefile.java:52)
    at writefile.Writefile.main(Writefile.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

I do not know how to fix this. I'm not sure how to fiz the floating decimal or empty string error.The file has weird symbols in it, no integers. How do I fix this? Please be specific please as I'm only a beginner at Java.

Comment: Which line(s) cause the exception -- lines 52 and 19 of Writefile.java?

Answer (score 2):

`outputWriter.write(1);` does not mean `outputWriter.write("1");`
you need change `outputWriter.write(Num);`  to `outputWriter.write(""+Num);`
please refer `outputstream.write(int)`

Comment: This is the root of the problem. However, you should refer OP to [`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) (since `outputWriter` is a `BufferedWriter`). Also, it's clearer, and possibly more efficient (depending on the compiler) to use `Integer.toString(Num)` rather than `""+Num`.

Comment: yeah, totally agree. Or use `String.valueOf(Num)`. Thanks. And a question, what about `outputWriter.write('0' + Num)`?

Comment: Um, `'0' + Num` would not do anything good. It only works if `-1 < Num < 10` (what happens if the loop limits change?) and it's opaque. Regarding `String.valueOf(Num)`: it just turns around and calls `Integer.toString(Num)`, so you might as well call that directly. (I also like it because it's a little more self-documenting; `String.valueOf()` is heavily overloaded, so you have to remember the type of `Num`, while `Integer.toString()` is clearly formatting an `int` as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because `line` is an empty string at some point, test for this before parsing the string:

```
while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
         number = Double.parseDouble(line);
         // rest of loop
    }
}
```

That is, assuming that the line contains only numbers. If there are other characters, you'll have to perform a more careful validation before parsing the line.

Comment: I usually do `if (line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {...}` 1+

Comment: The line could simply have non-numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

> The file has weird symbols in it, no integers.

From [`BufferedWriter#write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29):

> Writes a single character.

So it's not writing the `int` value you're sending to it, instead its character representation.

It would be better if you just write the numeric value as `String` and then retrieve it as `String` and parse it. In your `writeToFile` method, modify this part

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    Num = reader.nextInt ();
    outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(Num));      
    if(i!=6) {
        outputWriter.newLine();
    }
}
```